# convert rows to column in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
------------------------------------------------------------
courseid|course    |coursedesc                             |
------------------------------------------------------------
 1      | BSIT     |  Bachelor of science in info tech     |
 2      | BSCS     |   Bachelor of science in comp sci     |
 3      | BSHRM    |  Bachelor of science in hotel & res   |
```

I want to convert it to something like this **dynamically**

```
---------------------------------
|course1 | course2   | course3  |
---------------------------------
 BSIT     | BSCS     | BSCS     |
```

I have this code and giving me  Result :

## MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'count(case when course = ''',
      course,
      ''' then 1 end) AS ',
      replace(course, ' ', '')
    )
  ) INTO @sql
from tbl_course;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT course, ', @sql, ' from tbl_course

group by course');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Please stop shouting, and consider handling display issues in application code

Comment: sorry @Strawberry

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - Rows to Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns)

Answer (score 0):

**Query**

```
set @query = null;
select
  group_concat(distinct
    concat(
      'max(case when `courseid` = ',
      `courseid`, ' then `course` end) as `course', `courseid`, '`'
    )
  ) into @query
from `tbl_course`;

set @query = concat('select ', @query, ' from `tbl_course` ');

prepare stmt from @query;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

**[Find a demo here](http://rextester.com/JGDMN84336)**

Comment: It gives me the same result  # MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). @Wanderer

Comment: @MarkLopez : Is there any null values in any of those 2 columns?

Comment: None sir @Wanderer